# $D(A^2)$ is dense in $D(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $A$ is a densely-defined closed operator in a Hilbert space $H$, will $D(A^2)$ be dense in $D(A)$?

I know it is true if $A$ is self-adjoint as $D(A^2)$ is the core of $A$.

Comment: You might look at something like $Af=gf'$ where $g$ is not differentiable.